# Error in If function

Tags: function-construction

I defined a function which roles as operator and.

```
and[a_, b_] := If[a == true, b, false, "F"];
```

When the first implement is false the function outputs "F". For example, see the print.

```
Print[and[true,false]];
-------------------------------------------
F
```

What happens in this function? And how can I construct the function right way?

Comment: What do you want your function to *do*?  If it is a simple AND, why not &&?

Comment: It prints `false` for me, not `"F"`.

Comment: If I define `true := RandomReal[] x`, then `and[true, false]` prints `"F"` (almost always -- hasn't failed yet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
And[a,b]
```

and of course use *Mathematica*'s terms `True` and `False` (note the upper-case).

Example:

```
And[True, False]
```

(*
False 
*)

Comment: Oh, I made mistake on pretty basic thing. Thank you.